# Uploading files to google cloud storage bucket using googleCloudStorageR's gcs_upload for uniform bucket-level access

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform

Probably a usage or settings issue:

I'm trying to use `R`'s `googleCloudStorageR` package to upload files to my google storage bucket.

Running:

```
googleCloudStorageR::gcs_upload("test/my_test.csv")
```

prints these messages:

```
2020-05-11 18:57:19 -- File size detected as 368 bytes
2020-05-11 18:57:20> Request Status Code: 400
```

And then this error:

```
Error: API returned: Cannot insert legacy ACL for an object when uniform bucket-level access is enabled. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access.
```

Is there a different usage to `googleCloudStorageR::gcs_upload` that will succeed? (not clear from its [documentation](http://code.markedmondson.me/googleCloudStorageR/reference/gcs_upload.html)

If I set `predefinedAcl` to `"default"` I get a `JSON` related error:

```
Error : lexical error: invalid char in json text
```

This error message is followed by some `html` code and following that this message:

```
> xdg-open: unexpected argument 'minimum-scale=1,'
Try 'xdg-open --help' for more information.`.
```

I'm not sure what `JSON` it's referring to but if it's the `JSON` I set `googleCloudStorageR` to authenticate access to my bucket than I'm surprised it's complaining at this stage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been [resolved](https://github.com/cloudyr/googleCloudStorageR/issues/111) by the [googleCloudStorageR](https://github.com/cloudyr/googleCloudStorageR) developers. It is not yet on the `CRAN` distribution but it installing it from `github` (`devtools::install_github("cloudyr/googleCloudStorageR")`) should do.

And the usage is:

```
googleCloudStorageR::gcs_upload("test/my_test.csv", predefinedAcl = "bucketLevel")
```

Comment: are you still using the dev version for this to work? I'm using the CRAN version but am having the same error as you were above, tried switching to the dev version and it's still not working for me...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in https://github.com/cloudyr/googleCloudStorageR/pull/84 it got support to inherit the bucket level ACL if you set `predefinedAcl` to `default`. In your example this would be:

```
googleCloudStorageR::gcs_upload("test/my_test.csv", predefinedAcl = "default")
```

Comment: This produces a different error which I've updated my question with